# How to make Bean Validation API 1.1 works with GWT 2.7?

Tags: java, gwt, bean-validation

I use Bean Validation API 1.1 at server side and it works just well, however, I found gwt-user artifact has one dependency on Bean Validation 1.0, so conflict comes, if I exclude 1.0 from gwt-user maven dependency, it will complain when doing GWT compiling, If not exclude, server side is just stuck as it can not find necessary method in 1.1.

Any workaround for this? as I really need to use 1.1 at server side.
Thanks.

BTW I use gwt-maven-plugin 2.7 in my pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to share the same classpath for client and server code (I'd even say it's a bad practice).

In Maven land, that however means separating client and server code into distinct Maven modules.
See https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes for examples of how that can be done (note: latest snapshot is using `net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin`, not `org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin`! Look at older commits if you want examples using the `org.codehaus.mojo` plugin)